# Need to hide property of jQuery Datatable using local variable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using `jQuery Datatables` to display my data, as i am using it with HTML5, I want to make my code generic so that all the parameters can be passed in HTML.

My Datatable call looks like

`$('.search-result').dataTable({

    "bServerSide": serverside,

    "sAjaxSource": url,

    "aoColumnDefs": mSortingString,

    "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex){

    $(nRow).attr('data-title', "test");

    }
    });`

what i want to accomplish is to control `fnCreatedRow` parameter addition with some local variable like

`if (showrow){
    "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex){

    $(nRow).attr('data-title', "abc");

    }
    }`

I have tried above code but it doesn't work, is their any way to do what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
"fnCreatedRow": function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if (showrow) {
        $(nRow).attr('data-title', "abc");
    }
}
```

I don't think it is possible to control parameter addition as javascript/jquery code is loaded once and you cannot load the parameter, if the condition is true, without reloading the page.